# Can't get the input value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the value of two `input` for a price filter, so I get the min value then the max value and then use arrow function to get the objects.

html code

```
<div class="filters__mobile_all" style="display: none">
        <h4 class="price">Precio</h4>
        <div class="filter-price">
            <input class="input_price-min" id="input_price- 
            minList" type="value" placeholder="Mínimo">
            <input class="input_price-max" id="input_price- 
              maxList" type="value" placeholder="Máximo">
            <button class="establish-button" id="establishList">Establecer</button>
        </div>
    </div>


<div class="filter-price">
  <input class="input_price-min input_price-minList" id="input_price-minList" type="value" placeholder="Mínimo">
  <input class="input_price-max input_price-maxList" id="input_price-maxList" type="value" placeholder="Máximo">
  <button class="establish-button" id="establishList1">Establecer</button>
</div>

 <script> 
  var btnEstablecer = document.getElementById("establishList1");
  btnEstablecer.addEventListener("click", function() {
      let minPric = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_price- 
            minList ").value);

            let maxPric = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_price- 
              maxList ").value);                  
            });
 </script>
```

The actual otuput is `NaN`,

I found the solution, it was I have duplicate Html Id, I was using the same Id for mobile.

Comment: it's not `innerText`, it's `value`

Comment: `document.getElementById("input_price-minList").value`

Comment: none of those works, I tried with .value and .innertext and nothing

Comment: ` let minPric = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_price- 
   minList").innerText); ` because of this line. Input element have value attribute to get value

Comment: The console show me NaN in both with .value

Comment: take care with white spaces and line breaks on your code, it can affect the results, since: `input_price-minList ` is not the same that `input_price-minList` (note the empty sapce in the end

Comment: Where does `obj` come from? You're using it in your code, but you don't show where it's defined or anything.

Comment: the obj is not the problem im debuggin it and i'm getting NaN before obj

Comment: remove the white space after `input_price- 
            minList` from`document.getElementById("input_price- 
            minList ")` and also from `document.getElementById("input_price- 
              maxList ")`

Comment: If you try to run the code you posted as a snippet it throws an error, so it is a problem  - your code example is bad. Modify your example and remove it from the code if it's pointless.

Comment: I found the solution, it was I have duplicate Html Id, I was using the same Id for mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is exactly how you included it in your question, you have some syntax errors. First, you need to remove the erroneous whitespace causing those errors. Also, you should be accessing the value of an `input` element by using its `value` property, not `innerText`.

Fixing those items, this seems to work:

```js
var btnEstablecer = document.getElementById("establishList");
btnEstablecer.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let minPric = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_price-minList").value);

  let maxPric = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_price-maxList").value);

  console.log(minPric, maxPric);
});
```

```html
<div class="filter-price">
  <input class="input_price-min" id="input_price-minList" type="value" placeholder="Min">
  <input class="input_price-max" id="input_price-maxList" type="value" placeholder="Max">
  <button class="establish-button" id="establishList">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It works in the snippet above. How does your code differ? Also what is `obj`?

Comment: Well i'm still getting NaN and obj is excuted before I get minPric and maxPrice and twice shows NaN

Comment: I found the solution, it was I have duplicate Html Id, I was using the same Id for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet has many syntax errors; I fixed them but `obj` is undefined: I don't know what you want to achieve with this like

```
  obj.map(obj => obj.Precio_cop > minPric && obj.Precio_cop < maxPric ?
    elementosFilter.push(obj) : "");
```

Type errors like button name, input element ID is using space :|.

But I've try to fix your code and this is a working code snippet

```js
  var btnEstablecer = document.getElementById("establishList");  
   btnEstablecer.addEventListener("click", function(){  
   let minPric = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_price-minList").value);

   let maxPric = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_price-maxList").value);
 
   console.log("Min price :" + minPric +" max price :"+ maxPric);
      
    
});
```

```html
<div class="filter-price">
       <input class="input_price-min" id="input_price-minList" type="value" placeholder="Mínimo">
       <input class="input_price-max" id="input_price-maxList" type="value" placeholder="Máximo">
       <button class="establish-button" id="establishList">Establecer</button>                                  
</div>
```

Comment: i'm still getting NaN and obj is excuted before I get minPric and maxPrice and twice shows NaN –

Comment: obj is undefined!! how you can access obj. Please describe what is obj. PS: i know its a list

Comment: that is not the problem, the problem is that I get NaN before execute the obj it doesnt matter I edited my post.

Comment: please check in your script, is there any explicit call to btnEstablecer.click(). this can be the reason, NaN is coming. because before enter number in input field this buttons click function triggered and script try to get the value, ParseInt make ("") empty string, NaN

Comment: because code snippet is working. please let me know!! or you can send me the script I can investigate !!

Comment: I found the solution, it was I have duplicate Html Id, I was using the same Id for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

### It works fine don't know what the problem is

```js
var btnEstablecer = document.getElementById("establishList");
btnEstablecer.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let minPric = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_price-minList").value);

  let maxPric = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_price-maxList").value);

  console.log(minPric, maxPric);
});
```

```html
<div class="filter-price">
  <input class="input_price-min" id="input_price-minList" type="value" placeholder="Min">
  <input class="input_price-max" id="input_price-maxList" type="value" placeholder="Max">
  <button class="establish-button" id="establishList">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use .value property not innertext.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="filter-price">
      <input
        class="input_price-min"
        id="input_price-minList"
        type="number"
        placeholder="Mínimo"
      />
      <input
        class="input_price-max"
        id="input_price-maxList"
        type="number"
        placeholder="Máximo"
      />
      <button class="establish-button" id="establishList">Establecer</button>
    </div>

    <script>
      let btnEstablecer = document.getElementById('establishList');
      btnEstablecer.addEventListener('click', function() {
        let minPric = parseInt(
          document.getElementById('input_price-minList').value
        );

        let maxPric = parseInt(
          document.getElementById('input_price-maxList').value
        );

        console.log(minPric, maxPric);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```